# url manager show 404 error on contact page

Tags: yii

I'm trying to make  my url look like this `mysite.com/contact` unfortunately it shows a 404 error on the contact page. the login page works tho. the file is located in `protected/view/site/contact.php`

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                'urlFormat'=>'path',
                //'urlSuffix'=>'.html',
                'rules'=>array(
                    '<view:(about|terms|faq|privacy)>' => 'site/page',
                    '<action:(contact|login)>' => 'site/<action>',
                    '<action:(registration|create)>' => 'user/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                ),
                'showScriptName' => false,
            ),
```

Comment: Do you have a contact action?

Comment: You must have contact action to remove this error.

Comment: you mean `model/contactForm.php` ?

Comment: You must be sure that you have actionContact in your SiteController!

Comment: @secretlm thanks! works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have this in your SiteController.php

```
/**
 * Displays the contact page
 */
public function actionContact()
{
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $name='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->name).'?=';
            $subject='=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($model->subject).'?=';
            $headers="From: $name <{$model->email}>\r\n".
                "Reply-To: {$model->email}\r\n".
                "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
                "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8";

            mail(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'],$subject,$model->body,$headers);
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I render mine like so

```
'contact' => array('site/contact'),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Create .htaccess in your project folder with above code